# Dell XPS - new install 18.04: 60 seconds freeze before logout / resume / shutdown

Tags: nvidia, dell, 18.04, xps

On 17.04/17.10 the Dell XPS 15 9560 did all fine. After first upgrade to 18.04 LTS, no luck, and then reinstall several times with new images, each time same issue: system froze after entering password to login; on both X and Wayland. I fixed that by Ctrl-Alt-F2 instead of password and installing nvidia drivers. But then now I have sustained problem:

As the Nvidia card is sucking power and keeps my fans high, I normally work with discrete graphics. So, I selected Prime, Intel in Nvidia settings. After long wait, it is running discrete now, but:

1. I cant seem to go back to Nvidia in easy way
2. Resume after lid closed take 1,5 minute at least (serious issue for me)
3. Logout and Shutdown take about same time

This is on X, Wayland logout is fast and seems all fine.

Comment: Are you using X or Weyland? Have you tried both. I have an XPS 15 9550 that I installed onto fine yesterday. I did have a black screen on login the first install but I did a quick format. The second time I made a new partition 1mb smaller to be sure it was fresh and all is well. Happy to run any comparisons my side to help you debug.

Comment: This is on X. Just tried Wayland but that is running ok as far as I can tell now. I upgraded BIOS to the new 1.9, did not help.

Comment: Shame, the XPS 15 isn't officially supported, but does seem to work for the most part. Let me know if I can help at all.

Comment: Switching back and forth to Wayland completely blocks the login and I need to purge, reinstall nvidia and remove /etc/X11/xorg.conf ...  For now it's a pain ... Blaming nvidia so far: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/1752053

Comment: Maybe cheering too soon... but my Dell XPS 15 is running Ubuntu 18.04 fine since two days. Only in discrete graphics mode, but that is my main usage anyway as power consumption and noise are essential for me.

Comment: Still not ideal. I am having minor issues with NVIDIA drivers my side, though it's just a minor audio stutter say when I watch a youtube video and scroll down, when it loads in the comments I get a stutter. Not noticed the fans being excessive, though that is hard to tell on my rig.